# How to change path for data storage for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, centos6

I have gone into my elasticsearch.yml and changed "path.data:" to the path where I want to store the data. Now when I start the elasticsearch service, the localhost:9200 would not work anymore. If I kept "path.data:" line commented out, localhost:9200 would work fine. I am on a centos 6 machine and I installed elasticsearch through yum. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured out the solution, I did not have permissions to make changes to the folder of where the new data would be stored in

Comment: Add an answer to this question yourself. It's not forbidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I had created the folder using the root folder, so elasticsearch did not have permissions to make changes to the folder where the new data would be stored in. IF you have any issues like this, make sure you have changed your permissions for the newly created folder.